# Why does allocations graph in instruments show no increase yet marked generations show memory growth

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-instruments

I am testing memory issues in allocations instruments and something seems strange. Allocations graph, shown in blue, shows no increase (even you can see little decrease -- look at the red markers) but  you can see memory growth in generation snapshots. Why is it inconsistent?

[image]

Comment: You generations are growing by 87-123kb, but that's visually indiscernible on an allocations chart, whose peak looks like it must have been 15mb or so.

Comment: I thought so too but area height seems to be decreasing. I was wondering if i was doing something wrong and if was adding up those spikes (it shouldnt, allocation lifespan set to created and still iving). I will accept your answer if you post it below. I will just have to assume graph is not perfect

Comment: What operations are done in each generation ?

Comment: I am generating bunch of SKSpriteNode objects (and some of their subclasses), moving them around (animating) and before each mark generation click, removing everything from the SKScene. It is supposed to release all memory but it does not apparently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your generations are growing by 87-123kb, but that's visually indiscernible on an allocations chart, whose peak looks like it must have been 15mb or so.
2. If you look at those valleys where you marked your generations, it looks like they're lower, but if you look at your image carefully in a photo editing tool (draw a horizontal line), they're really not.
3. Even if they were lower, the generations tool will show you items that were allocated but not released. It does not net out those items that we deallocated in the process, too.

   [image]

   Look at generation C, which in this case really is much lower, but the "growth" is just showing us what objects that were allocated but not released between generation B and C.

Comment: No wonder the growth is never negative, by the way, how do you get to know this, is there any good reference that explains Instrument in more detail?

Comment: The WWDC videos are very helpful. E.G. [WWDC 2013 Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410). Or [WWDC 2012 iOS Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242). Or if you want to branch beyond memory issues, videos like [Building Concurrent User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211). Bottom line, many of the WWDC videos on various topics have nice, practical demonstrations of using Instruments.